# Efficiently perform row-wise distribution test

Tags: r, optimization, rollapply

I have a matrix in which each row is a sample from a distribution. I want to do a rolling comparison of the distributions using `ks.test` and save the test statistic in each case. The simplest way to implement this conceptually is with a loop:

```
set.seed(1942)
mt <- rbind(rnorm(5), rnorm(5), rnorm(5), rnorm(5))

results <- matrix(as.numeric(rep(NA, nrow(mt))))

for (i in 2 : nrow(mt)) {

  results[i] <- ks.test(x = mt[i - 1, ], y = mt[i, ])$statistic

}
```

However, my real data has ~400 columns and ~300,000 rows for a single example, and I have a lot of examples. So I'd like this to be fast. The Kolmogorov-Smirnov test isn't all that mathematically complicated, so if the answer is "implement it in `Rcpp`," I'll grudgingly accept that, but I'd be somewhat surprised -- it's already very fast to compute on a single pair in R.

Methods I've tried but have been unable to get working: `dplyr` using `rowwise/do/lag`, `zoo` using `rollapply` (which is what I use to generate the distributions), and populating a `data.table` in a loop (edit: this one works, but it's still slow).

Comment: Are you actually using the `KernSmooth` package? `ks.test` is in the `stats` package.

Comment: You are correct! I am using KernSmooth, but not for this function -- I'm using it to generate the distributions. I'll edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick and dirty implementation in Rcpp

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h> 

double KS(arma::colvec x, arma::colvec y) {
  int n = x.n_rows;
  arma::colvec w = join_cols(x, y);
  arma::uvec z = arma::sort_index(w);
  w.fill(-1); w.elem( find(z <= n-1) ).ones();
  return max(abs(cumsum(w)))/n;
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector K_S(arma::mat mt) {
  int n = mt.n_cols; 
  Rcpp::NumericVector results(n);
  for (int i=1; i<n;i++) {
    arma::colvec x=mt.col(i-1);
    arma::colvec y=mt.col(i);
    results[i] = KS(x, y);
    }
  return results;
}
```

for matrix of size `(400, 30000)`, it completes under 1s.

```
system.time(K_S(t(mt)))[3]
#elapsed 
#   0.98
```

And the result seems to be accurate.

```
set.seed(1942)
mt <- matrix(rnorm(400*30000), nrow=30000)
results <- rep(0, nrow(mt))
for (i in 2 : nrow(mt)) {
  results[i] <- ks.test(x = mt[i - 1, ], y = mt[i, ])$statistic
}
result <- K_S(t(mt))
all.equal(result, results)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: That's fast. I'll test it out!

Comment: That's crazy fast. Excellent work. For comparison, I stopped my `rollapplyr()` solution after about 2 hours (it had generated nearly all the results at that point but was still running). Does it match the results from `ks.test()`?

Comment: I didn't check for the accuracy, hence the identifier "dirty".

Comment: Not quite, but it's damn close: `all.equal(results.ks2, results.cpp[2:280007])
[1] "Mean relative difference: 7.642923e-05"`. And it's approximately 9x faster than `ks.test2` on my actual data.

Comment: Given the performance and acceptable accuracy, I'd say this is likely to be your best solution, @Ajar.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks all for the great input!

Answer (score 3):

One source of speed up is to write a smaller version of `ks.test` that does less. `ks.test2` below is more restrictive than `ks.test`. It assumes, for example, that you have no missing values and that you always want the statistic associated with a two-sided test.

```
ks.test2 <- function(x, y){

  n.x <- length(x)
  n.y <- length(y)
  w <- c(x, y)
  z <- cumsum(ifelse(order(w) <= n.x, 1/n.x, -1/n.y))

  max(abs(z))

}
```

Verify that the output is consistent with `ks.test`.

```
set.seed(999)
x <- rnorm(400)
y <- rnorm(400)

ks.test(x, y)$statistic

    D 
0.045

ks.test2(x, y)

[1] 0.045
```

Now determine the savings from the smaller function:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  ks.test(x, y),
  ks.test2(x, y)
  )

Unit: microseconds
           expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval cld
  ks.test(x, y) 1030.238 1070.303 1347.3296 1227.207 1313.8490 6338.918   100   b
 ks.test2(x, y)  709.719  730.048  832.9532  833.861  888.5305 1281.284   100  a
```

Comment: I'd be interested to see a benchmark of my `rollapplyr()` solution using this function in place of `ks.test()`. I'll test that out once the current benchmark finishes.

Comment: I'll be very interested in this as well! I'm currently testing out some of these answers myself.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to compute the pairwise Kruskal-Wallis statistic using `ks.test()` with `rollapplyr()`.

```
results <- rollapplyr(data = big,
                      width = 2,
                      FUN = function(x) ks.test(x[1, ], x[2, ])$statistic,
                      by.column = FALSE)
```

This gets the expected result, but it's slow for a dataset of your size. Slow slow slow. This may be because `ks.test()` is computing a lot more than just the statistic at each iteration; it also gets the p-value and does a lot of error checking.

Indeed, if we simulate a large dataset like so:

```
big <- NULL
for (i in 1:400) {
    big <- cbind(big, rnorm(300000))
}
```

The `rollapplyr()` solution takes a long time; I halted execution after about 2 hours, at which point it had computed nearly all (but not all) results.

It seems that while `rollapplyr()` is likely faster than a `for` loop, it will not likely be the best overall solution in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution that gets the same result as your loop. I have my doubts if this is actually faster than the loop, but perhaps it can serve as a first step towards a solution.

```
require(dplyr)
mt %>% 
  as.data.frame %>%
  mutate_each(funs(lag)) %>%
  cbind(mt) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  do({
    x = unlist(.)
    n <- length(x)
    data.frame(ks = ks.test(head(x, n/2), tail(x, n/2))$statistic)
  }) %>%
  unlist %>%
  c(NA, .) %>%
  matrix
```