# Faster way to generate large list of vectors from permuted datasets [R]

Tags: r, performance, list, permutation

**Setup** For the purposes of my simulation, I'm generating a list of `B=2000` elements, with each element being the output of a permutation procedure in which I first permute the rows of a `200x8000` matrix and *for each column*, I calculate the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic between the *first and second 100 rows* (you can think of the first 100 rows as data from one group and the second 100 rows as data from another group).

**Question** This process takes a very long time (about 30-40 minutes) to generate the list. Is there a much faster way? In the future, I'd like to increase `B` to a larger value.

**Code**

```
B=2000
n.row=200; n.col=8000
#Generate sample data
samp.dat = matrix(rnorm(n.row*n.col),nrow=n.row)

perm.KS.list = NULL
for (b in 1:B){
    #permute the rows
    perm.dat.tmp = samp.dat[sample(nrow(samp.dat)),]
    #Compute the permutation-based test statistics
    perm.KS.list[[b]]= apply(perm.dat.tmp,2,function(y) ks.test.stat(y[1:100],y[101:200]))
}


#Modified KS-test function (from base package)
ks.test.stat <- function(x,y){
  x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  n <- length(x)
  y <- y[!is.na(y)]
  n.x <- as.double(n)
  n.y <- length(y)
  w <- c(x, y)
  z <- cumsum(ifelse(order(w) <= n.x, 1/n.x, -1/n.y))
  z <- z[c(which(diff(sort(w)) != 0), n.x + n.y)] #exclude ties
  STATISTIC <- max(abs(z))
  return(STATISTIC)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851637/efficiently-perform-row-wise-distribution-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `1:B` loop has several places to optimize, but I agree that the real consumer is that inner function.  Because you're simulating your well-behaved bootstrap samples, you can make two simplifying assumptions that the general `base` function can't:

1. There aren't missing values.  This obviates the `is.na()` adjustments
2. The two sides (ie, `x` & `y`) have the same number of elements, so you don't need to count them separately.  instead of splitting `y` in the loop, and them joining them back in the function (into `w`), just keep it together.  The balanced sides also permit simplifications like remove the `ifelse()` clause.  It produces a bunch of 0/1s, which are rescaled to -1/1s with integer arithmetic.

The function is reduced, which saves about 25% of the time.  I added integers, instead of doubles inside `cumsum()`.

```
ks.test.stat.balanced <- function(w){
  n     <- as.integer(length(w) * .5)
  # z   <- cumsum(ifelse(order(w) <= n, 1L, -1L)) / n
  z     <- cumsum((order(w) <= n)*2L - 1L) / n
  # z   <- z[c(which(diff(sort(w)) != 0), n + n)] #exclude ties
  return( max(abs(z)) )
}
```

Ties shouldn't occur often with your gaussian rng, and the `diff(sort(.))` is very expensive.  If you're willing to remove that protection, the time is reduced by about 65%.

If you move the equation for `z` into `abs()`, it saves a little time over all those reps.  I kept it separate above, so it's easier to read.

*edit* in case of an unbalanced simulation I'd recommend you:

1. still keep out the `is.na`,
2. still pass `w`,
3. still keep as much as possible in `integer`, not `numeric`, but
4. now include arguments `n1` & `n2` for the two group sizes.

Also, experiment w/ precalculating 1/`n` before `cumsum()` to avoid a lot of expensive divisions.  Try to think of other math-y ways to extract calculations from an inner loop so it occurs less frequently.

Comment: Thanks! I do want to have some flexibility in allowing `x` and `y` to have differing lengths, but for the purposes of simulation, I think it should be ok to have them equal. Would I keep my original code for the case of different lengths?

Comment: @stats134711, I added suggestions for unbalanced code in the answer.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. It should be pretty easy to weight based on `n1` and `n2`.